# How to pass pointer to a container from function?

Tags: raku

I can bind containers to new names:

```
my %h;
my $p := %h{ "a" }{ "b" }{ "c" };
$p = 1;
say %h;
```

Which outputs expected:

```
{a => {b => {c => 1}}}
```

But what if I need to return such pointer from subroutine?

```
my %h;
sub get-pointer {
    my $p := %h{ "a" }{ "b" }{ "c" };
    return $p;
};
my $q := get-pointer();
$q = 1;
say %h;
```

Gives:

```
Cannot assign to a readonly variable or a value
```

That thing puzzles me - `$p.WHERE` and `$q.WHERE` give the same address, so why is it suddenly read-only?

Answer (score 16):

Nevermind, I had some tunnel-vision moment and wanted aliases to behave as C pointers.

Found it clearly explained here at [Raku Documentation](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/return-rw).

> The sub return will return values, not containers. Those are immutable
>
> To return a mutable container, use return-rw.